# cause an IE8 browser running in compatibility mode to run without it!

Tags: facebook, ie8-compatibility-mode

this is quite frustrating, I saw many questions around this topic, but strangely enough non seem to address my issue.

I have a facebook application that works just great in IE8.
Thing is, it runs inside an iframe, which means that facebook causes the browser to render in IE compatibility mode, while my application wants to run with just simple IE8.

the meta tag http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  doesn't seem to have any influence.

What can I do?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an iFrame inherits the parents' Compatibility mode no matter what you do in the HTML of your iFrame. So, the answer is, the only thing you can do is make sure your HTML and styles work fine in IE7 in this case.